# Android Gradle Build Error

Tags: android

I am adding dependencies in build.gradle file.

My code is :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1'
```

}

I got error :

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages

Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
     In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

How to solve this problem.
Please help me ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try by adding this in your build.gradle (Module: app). It solved my issue:

```
packagingOptions{
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

My final build gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.camerafileupload"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
}
```

NB: In my case I have pasted this 3 jars in my libs folder. You can download and do so.

Comment: Good answer! Thank you

Comment: But, what if we compile/download file from package_name:version in app gargle instead of picking  up from libs folder

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by replacing following line

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1"
```

with this

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1"
```

Please visit following URL if you want to know more about **HttpClient for Android**

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Answer (score 3):

I solved the Issue by Using This if your compileSdkVersion is 19(IN MY CASE)

```
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

else if your compileSdkVersion is 23
then use

```
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `exclude` to each library, you can add following configuration for all libraries:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents',module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**If Nothing works try this one .definitely work**

replace this

```
 dependencies {
......
.......
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1'
}
```

with below code

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```